# Keep playing audio when changing page

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm using  to play music on my home page, but when i change the page to player stops.

Is there a solution to keep the player running even if we go to another page ?

Comment: Do not change the page, do an `AJAX` request and update the page.

Comment: You are using.... to play music?

Comment: unless you want to build a single page app Ali's suggestion is the easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Show Page content in iframe. Keep music player alive in the main page. When you want to change the page, change the content of the iframe. Use **pushstate** to change the URL of browser without reloading the page. Thats what music site like saavn.com do.

Comment: Each page is in an html file, and the first page contains <audio> and other items, and when I want to go to the second, I want to display another content without displaying the audio player but the latter must continue playing music

Comment: Hi @user7350434, You need to create a master html file, which will have a <iframe> and a <audio>, when you navigate to other pages, change the content of <iframe> loading the next page, hide the audio player and change the url of main page using pushstate. All with little bit of javascript is easily possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single page and dynamically change the elements on the page (or for example create a container element which will have the page content).

You can change the URL of the page using *pushState*.

More on **pushState**:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState

The code is very messy for now but that's what I did for one of my projects:
https://github.com/Animenosekai/Project_Erina/blob/master/ErinaServer/Erina/static/scripts/main.js#L62